# Assign an object reference to a variable

Tags: delphi, object, reference, free, assign

I have a question about assign here, I want to know

1. whether `Assign` makes a copy of the whole object and
2. I would like to know whether `FTEA.Objects[0]` is also freed.

I want to make a copy of `FTEA.Objects[0]` and when I free `ObjCur`, I don't intend to free `FTEA.Objects[0]` - not sure the correct way of doing this, need your help, thanks :

```
function xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
var 
  curQuo, tempQuo:TXX_TEA;
begin
  curQuo :=TXX_TEA(FTEA.Objects[0]);
  if xxxxxxxxx then
  begin
    tempQuo := TXX_TEA.Create();
    tempQuo.Assign(curQuo);   // Question 1: Assign copy the whole object value or not
    objCur.AddQuo(tempQuo)
  end
  else
    TXX_TEA(objCur.Quos[0]).Assign(curQuo);
  end;

  finally
    objCur.Free; // Question 2: FTEA.Objects[0] is freed or not
  end;
end
```

Comment: Downvoted for useless question.

Comment: @spspli: I agree with @Warren (although I didn't downvote). Trying to post sample code that uses things like `function xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and `if xxxxxxx` and `TXX_TEA` makes it difficult to read and understand. Post your actual code (making only changes necessary for privacy and so forth). Posting useless sample code makes it difficult to give you useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign is a routine that must be implemented per class, so it does what it is programmed to do. It is *supposed* to try to copy the entire object that is passed as argument, as well as it can. But if it can't, it probably shouldn't copy anything.

Some classes may have implementations that do not conform to that unenforced "contract" and only copy the parts they need. In other words, what gets copied is completely up to the implementation.

Assign has no special meaning and is a normal function, not some kind of compiler magic. It does not do anything to the object passed as parameter, so freeing one object does not affect the other. The objects are totally independent.

Note that not all classes implement Assign. You may think you call the Assign for the class, but it may actually be the inherited Assign, which does not know anything about any new members in the derived class to be copied. The notion of Assign is nice, but unfortunately, it is often not implemented or not implemented properly.

Comment: I checked the code, the assign implemented correctly, it assigns each property. Thanks for the answer.FTEA.Objects[0] is not freed here.

Comment: Good to know it implements Assign properly. IME, that is not always the case, in 3rd party code.

Answer (score 5):

No, freeing one object that has been Assigned from another object does not free the source object.

How Assign will function depends entirely on the class. Each class has to implement Assign and then call inherited and assign its own custom properties from source to destination if the classes are compatible. I'd recommend looking at the source for these classes to check if they implement Assign.

Comment: I checked they implement assign and assign each property from source to the class object. So tempQuo.Assign(curQuo) you think it will assign each property of the object curQuo pointing to to tempQuo object?

Comment: Spspli, rather than asking what a bunch of strangers what they *think* will happen, why don't you just run your code and *see* whether the properties are copied to the new object? You've already been told what's supposed to happen, so check it out. This is programming, not philosophy.

Comment: @Rob: +1 for "programming, not philosophy." It always bugs me when I see two coders at work arguing about whether doing X in the program will cause effect Y or effect Z.  Sometimes I get fed up and tell them, "Just run it and see what happens!"